# Таймер каждые 24 часа

Tags: php

После того как таймер доходит до `00:00:00`, он делает `00:00:0-1`, а потом, вместо того чтоб написать `23:59:59`, он пишет `24:19:06`. Откуда он берет 19 минут... Вот этот кусок кода который отвечает за это: `<span id=\"deptimer". $row['id'] ."\"></span>`

**P.S:** Скрипт писал не я, но мне суждено с ним разобраться.

Comment: Дубль вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684161/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b5

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема в скрипте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/684161/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1):

Вы привели пример вывода данных. Это ни о чем не говорит. Приведите пример кода, который отвечает за параметр `$row['id']`.

---

**P.S. По требованию Darth:**

Ищите место, где заполняется поле `nextdate` таблицы `plans`. Данный скрипт только выводит информацию по платежам. Какой-нибудь запрос, который обновляет таблицу - `UPDATE plans`. Посмотрите какие триггеры выполняются в базе данных, которые привязаны к таблицам `deposits`, `plans`, `users`.

Comment: код скинул на файлообменик,он не большой http://dropmefiles.com/arE7t

Comment: я сам смотрел и не понял где там есть пересечения у них,толь для запроса БД

Comment: Ищите где заполняется поле  _nextdate_ таблицы _plans_. Данный скрипт только выводит информацию по платежам. Какой-нибудь запрос, который обновляет таблицу `UPDATE plans`. Посмотрите какие триггеры выполняются в базе данных, которые привязаны к таблицам _deposits_ , _plans_, _users_

Comment: @GlWhitefoot поле "nextdate" есть только в таблице "deposits",тригеров нет ни где, а в deposits данные сваливаются из другой страницы - "deposit" вот код http://dropmefiles.com/8Y32k

Comment: Что мне видится из представленного кода: 1. формирование даты происходит в строках 35-68, 2. вероятно дата неправильно рассчитывается в строках 57-68, 3. неправильно она рассчитывается, потому что функция cfgSET возвращает время, соответствующее не 00:00:00 текущего дня, а  00:19:00. Посему, проанализируйте как она работает и откуда берет данные, и как они туда попадают.

Comment: @GlWhitefoot спасибо буду смотреть.1 - а это в этом же файле она берет данные или нет?  2 - и как вы поняли что функция cfgSET 00:19:00. А так спасибо большое за направление куда двигаться !

Comment: @АндрейАндрей, 1. данные берутся в строке 15 из БД. 2.это единственная "мутная" функция в коде, где может проявляться баг, хотя участок кода с 40 по 56 тоже может некорректно работать. Вообще советую вам установить эклипс и настроить дебаггер кода, чтобы вести отладку. Плюс стоит использовать ООП, что позволит упорядочить код и лучше понимать его структуру.

Comment: @GlWhitefoot 1 - Но в таблице "plans"  нет значения cfgSET!                                   Строчка 15 - $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM plans WHERE id = ".$plan." LIMIT 1"); скриншот http://dropmefiles.com/EhOCU

Comment: _  Но в таблице "plans" нет значения cfgSET! _ Это функция в коде, причем здесь значение таблицы. Плюс на картинке список полей(столбцов) таблицы, но никак не значений

Comment: @GlWhitefoo я понял. Значит надо копаться в самом коде который я скинул выше.

Comment: @bad4iz может вы сможете как то помочь)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена!

```
$nextdate = $nextdate + $row['moroz'] * 3600;
```